# My last function(showSelectedGoal) is showing NAN

Tags: javascript, html, function, parseint

When i call my third and last function(showSelectedGoal) it will show display NAN instead of what i asked for.

I tried parseInt on multiple of my codes, but unfortunately it is not working. I was thinking about the way my last function works. Because my 3th function is called at the same time as the other 2 functions. But the input of the 3th function is based on the output of the 2nd function. There might be something wrong with that.

```js
/* $(function()   {
           
            alert("hello?");
            
        }); */

function showBMI() {
  //event.preventDefault();

  var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
  var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
  var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;

  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = (gewicht / (lengte * lengte) * 10000).toFixed(2);
};

function harrisBenedict() {
  //event.preventDefault();

  var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
  var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
  var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;
  var geslacht = document.getElementById("user_geslacht").value;
  var activiteit = document.getElementById("user_activiteit").value;

  if (geslacht == "m") {
    var man = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (66.5 + (13.75 * gewicht) + (5.003 * lengte) - (6.755 * leeftijd));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
    //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
  } else if (geslacht == "v") {
    var vrouw = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (665.1 + (9.563 * gewicht) + (1.850 * lengte) - (4.676 * leeftijd));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
};

function revisedHarrisBenedict() {
  //event.preventDefault();

  var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
  var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
  var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;
  var geslacht = document.getElementById("user_geslacht").value;
  var activiteit = document.getElementById("user_activiteit").value;

  if (geslacht == "m") {
    var man = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (88.362 + (13.397 * gewicht) + (4.799 * lengte) - (5.677 * leeftijd));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
    //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
  } else if (geslacht == "v") {
    var vrouw = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (447.593 + (9.247 * gewicht) + (3.098 * lengte) - (4.330 * leeftijd));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
};

function mifflinStJeor() {
  //event.preventDefault();

  var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
  var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
  var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;
  var geslacht = document.getElementById("user_geslacht").value;
  var activiteit = document.getElementById("user_activiteit").value;

  if (geslacht == "m") {
    var man = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      ((10 * gewicht) + (6.25 * lengte) - (5 * leeftijd) + 5);
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
    //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
  } else if (geslacht == "v") {
    var vrouw = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      ((10 * gewicht) + (6.25 * lengte) - (5 * leeftijd) - 161);
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
};

function katchMcArdle() {
  //event.preventDefault();
  var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
  var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
  var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;
  var geslacht = document.getElementById("user_geslacht").value;
  var activiteit = document.getElementById("user_activiteit").value;
  var vetvrijemassa = document.getElementById("user_vvm").value;

  if (geslacht == "m") {
    var man = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (370 + (21.6 * vetvrijemassa));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
    //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
  } else if (geslacht == "v") {
    var vrouw = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (370 + (21.6 * vetvrijemassa));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
};

function cunningham() {
  //event.preventDefault();
  var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
  var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
  var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;
  var geslacht = document.getElementById("user_geslacht").value;
  var activiteit = document.getElementById("user_activiteit").value;
  var vetvrijemassa = document.getElementById("user_vvm").value;

  if (geslacht == "m") {
    var man = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (370 + (22 * vetvrijemassa));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (man * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
    //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
  } else if (geslacht == "v") {
    var vrouw = document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
      (370 + (22 * vetvrijemassa));
    if (activiteit == "1") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.2).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "2") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.375).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "3") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.55).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "4") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.7).toFixed(2);
    } else if (activiteit == "5") {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML =
        (vrouw * 1.9).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
};

function showBMR() {
  //event.preventDefault();
  var formule = document.getElementById("user_formule").value;

  if (formule == "1") {
    harrisBenedict();
  } else if (formule == "2") {
    revisedHarrisBenedict();
  } else if (formule == "3") {
    mifflinStJeor();
  } else if (formule == "4") {
    katchMcArdle();
  } else if (formule == "5") {
    cunningham();
  }
};
// this is the code i am referring to.       

function showSelectedGoal() {

  var jouwdoel = document.getElementById("user_jouwdoel").value;
  var BMR = document.getElementById('display2').value;

  if (jouwdoel == "1") {
    //  Afvallen(normaal) 15%
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 85).toFixed(2);
    //  Afvallen(aggresief) 20%
  } else if (jouwdoel == "2") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 80).toFixed(2)
    //  Afvallen(extreem) 25%
  } else if (jouwdoel == "3") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 75).toFixed(2);
    //  Onderhouden
  } else if (jouwdoel == "4") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 100).toFixed(2);
    //  Aankomen(voorzichtig) 5%
  } else if (jouwdoel == "5") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 105).toFixed(2);
    //  Aankomen(normaal) 10%
  } else if (jouwdoel == "6") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 110).toFixed(2);
    // Aankomen(aggresief) 15%
  } else if (jouwdoel == "7") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * 115).toFixed(2);
    //  Custom
  } else if (jouwdoel == "8") {
    document.getElementById('display3').innerHTML =
      ((BMR / 100) * document.getElementById('user_eigeninvulling').value).toFixed(2);
  };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <h1> BMI Calculator</h1>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section_1">
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="input_label_lengte"><b>Lengte</b></label>
          <input class="input_lengte" type="number" name="message" id="user_lengte" required><span class="span_lengte">cm</span><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="input_label_gewicht"><b>Gewicht</b></label>
          <input class="input_gewicht" type="number" name="message" id="user_gewicht" required><span class="span_gewicht">kg</span><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="input_label_leeftijd"><b>Leeftijd</b></label>
          <input class="input_leeftijd" type="number" name="message" id="user_leeftijd" required><span class="span_leeftijd">jr</span><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="select_label_geslacht"><b>Geslacht</b></label>
          <select class="select_geslacht" id="user_geslacht">
            <option value="m">Man</option>
            <option value="v">Vrouw</option>
          </select><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="select_label_formule"><b>Formule</b></label>
          <select class="select_formule" id="user_formule">
            <option value="1">Harris-Benedict</option>
            <option value="2">revised Harris-Benedict</option>
            <option value="3">Mifflin-St Jeor</option>
            <option value="4">Katch-McArdle</option>
            <option value="5">Cunningham</option>
          </select><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="select_label_activiteit"><b>Activiteit</b></label>
          <select class="select_activiteit" id="user_activiteit">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="input_label_vvm"><b>VetVrije Massa</b></label>
          <input class="input_vvm" type="number" name="message" id="user_vvm" required><span class="span_vvm">kg</span><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section_2">
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="select_label_jouwdoel"><b>Jouw Doel</b></label>
          <select class="select_jouwdoel" id="user_jouwdoel">
            <option value="1">Afvallen(normaal)</option>
            <option value="2">Afvallen(aggresief)</option>
            <option value="3">Afvallen(extreem)</option>
            <option value="4">Onderhouden</option>
            <option value="5">Aankomen(voorzichtig)</option>
            <option value="6">Aankomen(normaal)</option>
            <option value="7">Aankomen(aggresief)</option>
            <option value="8">Eigen Invulling</option>
          </select><br>
          <div class="form_groep">
            <label class="input_label_eigeninvulling"><b>Eigen Invulling</b></label>
            <input class="input_eigeninvulling" type="number" name="message" id="user_eigeninvulling" required><span class="span_eigeninvulling"></span><br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="input_label_calorienpercentage"><b>Calorien Percentage</b></label>
          <input class="input_calorienpercentage" type="number" name="message" id="user_doel_zelf"><span>%</span><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="select_label_standaardmacros"><b>Standaard Macros</b></label>
          <select class="select_standaardmacros" id="user_standaardmacros">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
          </select><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form_groep">
          <label class="input_label_macros"><b>Macros</b></label>
          <input class="input_macro_koolhydraten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_koolhyrdaten" required><span>Koolhydraten</span>
          <input class="input_macro_eiwitten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_eiwitten" required><span>Eiwitten</span>
          <input class="input_macro_vetten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_vetten" required><span>Vetten</span><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_1">
        <button class="button_reset" type="reset">Reset the form!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="button_2">
        <!-- This is the button which calls the 3 functions -->
        <button class="button_berekenen" type="button" onclick="showBMI();showBMR();showSelectedGoal();" value="Calculate">Berekenen</button><br/>
      </div>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="output">
      <label>BMI:</label>
      <p><span id='display'></span></p>
      <label>BMR:</label>
      <p><span id='display2'></span></p>
      <label>GOAL:</label>
      <p><span id='display3'></span></p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Key word in this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is **Minimal**. Can you reduce your code to only the problem space? Simplify your code please?

Comment: The problem is likely due to a fundamental misunderstanding of how JavaScript is designed to work. For example doing mathematics while believing JavaScript's automatic type conversion will work for you. you need extensive use of `.parseInt()` and `.parseFloat()` throughout your code.

Comment: `document.getElementById('display2').value` should be `document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML`. `display2` is a DIV, not an input.

Comment: If you just put `console.log(BMI)` in the function you would have seen that you weren't getting anything.

Comment: Thanks Randy Casburn. You are right, but since i am new to programming. I didn't know how i could minimize the code while being able to show the problem to others. But i will work on it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar that indeed fixed the problem!

Comment: You might want to look into how to debug your code, a start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger